# VBA Multiple Objects with 'With' Statement

Tags: ms-access, vba, with-statement

I have a check box that when checked multiple boxes are disabled on my form.
Currently im using

```
With Me!Textbox
.Locked = True
```

Is there a method where I can list multiple objects within the With statement rather than writing out each time for every textbox

e.g.

```
With Me!Text1, Text2, Text3
```

Comment: Yes you can use Controls Array. See this link: http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/vba-control-arrays/

Comment: Your link adds an abstraction which is attached to each element in a loop. Is there a way to use `with` to attach the abstraction instead of attaching it in a loop?

Comment: Updated link: http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/

Answer (score 2):

It may be easiest to add something to the tag property to identify the relevant controls, "lock", say. Then you can iterate over the controls collection and lock anything with a tag set to "lock".